# Can no longer boot due to "could not init core: -110" error

Tags: boot, drivers, wireless

Booting into Ubuntu 16.04 recently started stalling with the line:

> ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: Could not init core: -110

Full log in the following image:
[image]

Is there a hotkey to get into a shell from here? Anything I should try from there?

Comment: If you remove the wifi card it should boot

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's something to try. I'm somewhat cursed when it comes to all things hardware, so I might try exhausting all software options first...

Comment: If you get grub menu at boot, press e to edit, then scroll to the line with quiet splash and add `module_blacklist=ath10k_pci` then press F10 to boot